# CakePHP multi-HABTM associations with pagination

Tags: cakephp, pagination, cakephp-1.3, has-and-belongs-to-many

For an e-commerce app that I'm building I am using CakePHP.
I have created the db and afterwards baked my app with `cake bake`.
My models are all linked up properly as follows:

`Product hasMany CategoryProduct,ImagesProduct`

`Category hasMany CategoryProduct`

`CategoryProduct belongsTo Product,Category`

`Image hasMany ImagesProduct`

`ImagesProduct belongsTo Product,Image`

I have tried in various ways to obtain a paginated view of products dependent of the category_id with no succes.
I have managed to obtain the array I wanted  with
`$this->CategoryProducts->findByCategoryId($id)`, but I can't use the built-in paginator from cakePHP with the resultant array.

Could somebody tell me how to properly formulate the `$options['joins']` array to pass on to the paginate function in order to get the same result, but in a paginated way?

The SQL for what I want to do would be something like this:

`SELECT p . * , i.filename
FROM products p
LEFT JOIN (
category_products cp, categories c, images_products ip, images i
) ON ( cp.product_id = p.id
AND c.id = cp.category_id
AND c.id =2
AND ip.product_id = p.id
AND ip.image_id = i.id )`

Answer (score 1):

This is a question that perplexed me for quite sometime.  You shouldn't have to associate either of your join models (CategoryProduct, ImagesProduct) directly to your models if you're using a HABTM association with CakePHP.  `cake bake` may not have picked it up the HABTM association correctly if you didn't have the table names quite right.  The join tables should be `categories_products` and `images_products`, which would make th join models `CategoriesProduct` and `ImagesProduct`.

Either way though, the following should get you going on filtering by categories:

```
//in products_controller.php:

//Fake a HasOne association, setting the reset parameter to false since pagination
//requires two queries to complete (one for the count, one for the data)

$this->Product->bindModel(array(
    'hasOne' => array(
        'CategoriesProduct
    )
), false);

//Group by products since the HasOne will return multiple rows for each product

$options = array(
    'group' => 'Product.id',
    'conditions' => array(
        'CategoriesProduct.category_id' => $categories
    )
);

//To paginate the result:

$this->paginate = $options;
$products = $this->paginate();
```

In this example $categories can be either a single `category_id` or an array containing category_ids (i.e. `array('1', '2', '3')`).  The result will be an 'OR' of categories.  If you're looking to filter by an 'AND' type condition, check http://edblogs.cal.msu.edu/devteam/2011/02/08/cakephp-habtm-searches/.

Hope this helps.