# CakePHP Pagination with HABTM relationship

Tags: cakephp, pagination

I have a 'Club' HABTM 'Member' relationship.

From the ClubsController::View($id) view. I wish to show ALL the Members that belong to that ONE Club in a paginating table. I have tried many things but all were not exactly what I was looking for. The most common, seemingly related solution looked like [CakePHP multi-HABTM associations with pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5042134/cakephp-multi-habtm-associations-with-pagination) but this would give me ALL the 'Club' that belong to ONE 'Member' from the ClubsController. As apposed to ALL the 'Member' from the ONE 'Club' from the ClubsController. I feel this should be an obvious task.

Answer (score 2):

Im answering because I can't comment on Meibooms answer.
It's wrong, because there shouldn't be a `Member.club_id` field as its a **HABTM** relation.
Instead, what you should have is a join table: `ClubsMembers.club_id` `ClubsMembers.member_id`

As explained in the answer to the related question you mention, what you need to do is bind a fake hasOne relation to be able to set the conditions you want.

In your particular case:

```
        $this->Club->Member->bindModel(array(
            'hasOne' => array('ClubsMember')
        ), false);

        // Set up the paginate options array
        $this->paginate['Member'] = array(
            'contain' => array(
                'ClubsMember',
            ),
            'conditions' => array(
                'ClubsMember.club_id' => $club_id,
            ),
            //Group since the HasOne may return multiple rows for each
            //(if $club_id is an array of IDs and a Member is in more than one of those).
            'group' => 'Member.id',
            'order' => 'Member.name',
        );

        $this->set('members', $this->paginate('Member'));
```

Ignore the `contain` part if you don't use `ContainableBehavior`. (Cake will ignore it anyway.)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like a simple paginate on Member with the conditions of 'Member.club_id' => $id should do the trick for you.

ps. What version of CakePHP are you using? Newer versions are a bit more sophisticated with pagination afaik.

Comment: The newest version, Yes. I'll give that at try in the morning. Thanks.